# Find all differences between 2 strings

Tags: algorithm, array, vba

I pulled this out of my code bucket and dusted it off earlier today in response to a post over on SO that made me cringe.  This was originally written to highlight changes in Excel cells in real time via `Worksheet_Change`, so it is designed with an eye toward raw speed to avoid blocking the UI. Benchmarks on current hardware are running around 3 seconds to compare 2 1kb strings.

I cleaned it up a bit to modernize the coding style, but I'm mainly looking for input on the algorithm used and suggestions for making the code a bit more understandable for somebody who isn't familiar with it.

It basically works on byte arrays and tracks the current working position in each array with a set of index pointers for the "start" and "end" of each substring that it's working with.  The algorithm is similar to a binary search.  The entry point function finds the longest matching substring in the two byte arrays, excludes it, logs all the differences to the output, and then recursively calls itself on the slices of the arrays to the right and left of the match:

```
'Returns a comma delimited string containing the positions of differences in the passed byte arrays. Recursive.
'Arrays are not modified, index parameters specify where the pointers are in the arrays on each subsequent call.
Private Function FindDifferences(ByRef first() As Byte, ByRef other() As Byte, Optional ByVal firstStartIndex As Long = -1, _
                                 Optional ByVal firstEndIndex As Long, Optional ByVal otherStartIndex As Long, _
                                 Optional ByVal otherEndIndex As Long) As String

    If firstStartIndex = -1 Then
        'Find matching substrings and set index markers.
        SkipSubstringMatches first, other, firstStartIndex, firstEndIndex, otherStartIndex, otherEndIndex
        If firstEndIndex = -1 And otherEndIndex > 0 Then
            'All matches in first.
            Exit Function
        ElseIf otherEndIndex = -1 And firstEndIndex > 0 Then
            'All matches in other.
            FindDifferences = FormatIndexSpanForOutput(firstStartIndex, firstEndIndex)
            Exit Function
        ElseIf firstEndIndex = -1 And otherEndIndex = -1 Then
            'Identical input.
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Dim matchLength As Long
    Dim firstMatch As Long
    Dim otherMatch As Long

    FindNextMatch first, other, firstStartIndex, firstEndIndex, otherStartIndex, otherEndIndex, firstMatch, otherMatch, matchLength

    Dim differences As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    'Test to see if there are unmatched chars.
    If matchLength <> 0 Then
        differences = FindDifferences(first, other, firstStartIndex, firstMatch - 1, otherStartIndex, otherMatch - 1)
        If Len(differences) <> 0 Then returnValue = returnValue & "," & differences
        differences = FindDifferences(first, other, firstMatch + matchLength, firstEndIndex, otherMatch + matchLength, otherEndIndex)
        If Len(differences) <> 0 Then returnValue = returnValue & "," & differences
    Else
        returnValue = returnValue & "," & FormatIndexSpanForOutput(firstStartIndex, firstEndIndex)
    End If

    If Right$(returnValue, 1) = "," Then
        returnValue = Left$(returnValue, Len(returnValue) - 1)
    End If

    If Left$(returnValue, 1) = "," Then
        returnValue = Right$(returnValue, Len(returnValue) - 1)
    End If

    FindDifferences = returnValue
End Function
```

There are a couple helper functions for managing the array indexes - the first skips matching substrings in the 2 arrays:

```
'Sets ByRef index parameters to the position of the first mismatched byte from both the start and end. Arrays are not modified.
Private Sub SkipSubstringMatches(ByRef first() As Byte, ByRef other() As Byte, ByRef firstStartIndex As Long, _
                                 ByRef firstEndIndex As Long, ByRef otherStartIndex As Long, ByRef otherEndIndex As Long)

    Dim topFirst As Long
    Dim topOther As Long
    Dim baseFirst As Long

    topFirst = UBound(first)
    topOther = UBound(other)
    baseFirst = LBound(first)

    Dim lower As Long
    If topFirst >= topOther Then
        lower = topOther
    Else
        lower = topFirst
    End If

    Dim index As Long
    Do Until index > lower
        If first(index) <> other(index) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        index = index + 1
    Loop

    firstStartIndex = index
    otherStartIndex = index

    '-1 indicates all matches.
    If index > topFirst Then
        firstEndIndex = -1
        otherEndIndex = topOther
    ElseIf index > topOther Then
        otherEndIndex = -1
        firstEndIndex = topFirst
    End If

    If firstEndIndex = -1 Or otherEndIndex = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Do Until first(topFirst) <> other(topOther)
            topFirst = topFirst - 1
            topOther = topOther - 1
            If topFirst < baseFirst Or topOther < baseFirst Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        firstEndIndex = topFirst
        otherEndIndex = topOther
    End If
End Sub
```

...and a procedure that seeks the next match (finds the start and ending indexes of the mismatch):

```
'Advance indexes until the next matches are found.
Private Sub FindNextMatch(ByRef first() As Byte, ByRef other() As Byte, ByRef firstStartIndex As Long, _
                          ByRef firstEndIndex As Long, ByRef otherStartIndex As Long, ByRef otherEndIndex As Long, _
                          ByRef matchPositionFirst As Long, ByRef matchPositionOther As Long, ByRef matchLength As Long)

    Dim tempIndex As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Dim firstIndex As Long
    Dim otherIndex As Long

    For otherIndex = otherStartIndex To otherEndIndex
        firstIndex = firstStartIndex
        Do Until firstIndex >= firstEndIndex
            'Seek forward in first until there is a match.
            Do Until other(otherIndex) = first(firstIndex)
                firstIndex = firstIndex + 1
                If firstIndex = firstEndIndex Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            'Concurrently seek forward in both until a mismatch is found.
            tempIndex = otherIndex
            Do Until other(tempIndex) <> first(firstIndex)
                tempIndex = tempIndex + 1
                firstIndex = firstIndex + 1
                If firstIndex > firstEndIndex Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                If tempIndex > otherEndIndex Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            'Calculate match indexes and length.
            result = tempIndex - otherIndex
            If result > matchLength Then
                matchLength = result
                matchPositionOther = otherIndex
                matchPositionFirst = firstIndex - matchLength
            End If
            If matchLength > firstEndIndex - firstIndex Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        If matchLength + otherIndex > otherEndIndex Then
            'No possible matches left.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Finally, there's a helper function that formats the output.  This could be pretty much anything - in this case it's a comma delimited string of 1 based character indexes (that was the convenient output for the original calling code):

```
'Returns a comma delimited string of indexes between starting and ending, rebases to 1 base.
Private Function FormatIndexSpanForOutput(ByVal starting As Long, ByVal ending As Long) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    If starting = ending Then
        returnValue = CStr(ending + 1)
    Else
        Dim index As Long
        For index = starting To ending - 1
            returnValue = returnValue & CStr(index + 1) & ","
        Next index
        If starting < ending Then
            returnValue = returnValue & CStr(ending + 1)
        End If
    End If

    FormatIndexSpanForOutput = returnValue
End Function
```

...and a simple wrapper for calling it with string input instead of array input - note that this isn't unicode aware.

```
'Just a wrapper for passing strings instead of byte arrays.
Public Function StringDiffs(ByVal first As String, ByVal other As String) As String
    Dim firstChars() As Byte
    Dim otherChars() As Byte
    firstChars = StrConv(first, vbFromUnicode)
    otherChars = StrConv(other, vbFromUnicode)
    StringDiffs = FindDifferences(firstChars, otherChars)
End Function
```

For convenience (bad side-scrolling here), [the full module is also on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bCVDMUDs).

Sample usage:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim first As String
    Dim other As String

    first = "This is a test string."
    other = "This was a test thing."
    Debug.Print StringDiffs(first, other) & " in string 1 were deleted."
    Debug.Print StringDiffs(other, first) & " in string 2 were inserted."
End Sub
```

Output:

> ```
> 6,16,18 in string 1 were deleted. 
> 6,7,18 in string 2 were inserted.
> ```

Comment: @Raystafarian - Wow, I'm blind today. I get "2,4,12,13 in string 1 were deleted." and "2,3,12,14 in string 2 were inserted.", which is correct output.  Delete the 'e' in "test" and the 'hi' is "this" and the 's' is unchanged.  Then insert the 't' at the end of test.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, it's more of a transmutation of strings?

Comment: @Raystafarian - Yes and no - consider it like a diff file on, say, git or a Word document with track changes on.  The way it was originally used was to color text red and strike it through if it was "deleted" and color text that was added in green.  If you remove the character positions in the deletions from left to right, then insert the characters positions in the inserts from left to right it should give you the altered string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing much to complain about with this code, so here's a short list of opportunities that may or may not fall under the realm of personal preference:

Dual-branch conditional assignments like this, where there's only a single, non-side-effecting instruction in each branch:

> ```
> If topFirst >= topOther Then
>     lower = topOther
> Else
>     lower = topFirst
> End If
> ```

Can be written as a one-liner assignment with the `IIf` function:

```
lower = IIf(topFirst >= topOther, topOther, topFirst)
```

Single-liner conditional *blocks* that basically act as guard clauses:

> ```
> If firstIndex = firstEndIndex Then
>     Exit Do
> End If
> ```

Can be written with the conditional *statement* syntax:

```
If firstIndex = firstEndIndex Then Exit Do
```

Note that doing that removes a nesting level here:

> ```
> If firstEndIndex = -1 Or otherEndIndex = -1 Then
>     Exit Sub
> Else
>     Do Until first(topFirst) <> other(topOther)
>         topFirst = topFirst - 1
>         topOther = topOther - 1
>         If topFirst < baseFirst Or topOther < baseFirst Then
>             Exit Do
>         End If
>     Loop
>     firstEndIndex = topFirst
>     otherEndIndex = topOther
> End If
> ```

Becomes:

```
If firstEndIndex = -1 Or otherEndIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
Do Until first(topFirst) <> other(topOther)
    topFirst = topFirst - 1
    topOther = topOther - 1
    If topFirst < baseFirst Or topOther < baseFirst Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
firstEndIndex = topFirst
otherEndIndex = topOther
```

The declarations-as-close-as-possible-to-first-use style in `StringDiffs` wrapper function is not consistent with the rest of the code:

> ```
> Public Function StringDiffs(ByVal first As String, ByVal other As String) As String
>     Dim firstChars() As Byte
>     Dim otherChars() As Byte
>     firstChars = StrConv(first, vbFromUnicode)
>     otherChars = StrConv(other, vbFromUnicode)
>     StringDiffs = FindDifferences(firstChars, otherChars)
> End Function
> ```

Would have been:

```
Public Function StringDiffs(ByVal first As String, ByVal other As String) As String
    Dim firstChars() As Byte
    firstChars = StrConv(first, vbFromUnicode)

    Dim otherChars() As Byte
    otherChars = StrConv(other, vbFromUnicode)

    StringDiffs = FindDifferences(firstChars, otherChars)    
End Function
```

This bit looks a little *packed*, some vertical whitespace wouldn't hurt:

> ```
> If matchLength <> 0 Then
>     differences = FindDifferences(first, other, firstStartIndex, firstMatch - 1, otherStartIndex, otherMatch - 1)
>     If Len(differences) <> 0 Then returnValue = returnValue & "," & differences
>     differences = FindDifferences(first, other, firstMatch + matchLength, firstEndIndex, otherMatch + matchLength, otherEndIndex)
>     If Len(differences) <> 0 Then returnValue = returnValue & "," & differences
> Else
> ```

But otherwise the whole code looks great.